# Elasticsearch: optimizing query with filter and constant_score?

Tags: elasticsearch

In a Udemy tutorial I came across this query here:

```
{ "query": { "bool": {
    "must": {"match": {"genre": "Sci-Fi"}},
    "must_not": {"match": {"title": "trek"}},
    "filter:" {"range": {"year": {"gte": 2010, "lt": 2015}}}
}}}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to optimize it? I am thinking of two possible ways:

1. Putting "genre" in a filter context. But a movie might be of multiple genres, so I am not sure if working with type keyword and filter-term would work there.
2. Putting "must_not" in a filter context directly (without a bool) will not work, because filters as far as I understand do not allow "filtering out", only "filtering what to keep". But if I wrapped must_not in a constant_score or filter-bool, would the query be more performant? Or does ES automatically take care of such optimizations? I just don't understand why must_not is in the query and not filter context in the first place. Can something only partially not match and thus reduce the score only by a degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1:

Moving the `genre` match to the filter context might speed it up a little bit (even though that depends on so many other factors), but you'll lose the ranking, which might or might not be important to you. In the end, use `must` when ranking is important or `filter` if it's not and your only goal is to match a document or not given some criteria.

Moreover, using type keyword will only get you "exact match" semantics, it might be what you want... or not, depending on how you're creating the queries (user input or controlled pick list)...

Regarding 2:

`must_not` is [already in a filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), so it doesn't get any simpler than what you already see. The filter context is made up of both `filter` + `must_not`.

One last thing I would add and I always add when someone asks about performance optimization: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) so only do it when you are actually witnessing performance issues, never before.

Comment: Ah thank you, I thought something being in a filter/query-context means it can be wrapped inside the {...}-scope of filter or query. So it's a bit confusing that you can put must_not under query but not under filter if it does not contribute to the score.

Comment: This is so for historical reasons. If you check the link I shared, they explain how it works in depth. Glad I could clarify.